# Error while validating XML against XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I got a simple XML file that I want to validate against an XSD.
When I validate with some random validator, I always get the following error:

> Invalid content was found starting with element 'Entities'. One of '{Entities}' is expected.

Here's the XML:

```
<BusinessModel xmlns="http://schemas.testxyzxyz.de/xyz/BusinessModel" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Entities>
    <Entity Name="Customer">
        <Attribute Name="Forename" Type="String" />
        <Attribute Name="Surname" Type="String" />
        <Attribute Name="Birthday" Type="Date" />
    </Entity>
</Entities>
</BusinessModel>
```

As well as the XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        targetNamespace="http://schemas.testxyzxyz.de/xyz/BusinessModel"
        xmlns="http://schemas.testxyzxyz.de/xyz/BusinessModel">

<xsd:element name="BusinessModel" type="BusinessModelType" />

<xsd:complexType name="BusinessModelType">
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element name="Entities" type="EntitiesType" />
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="EntitiesType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Entity" type="EntityType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="AttributeType">
    <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
    <xsd:attribute name="Type" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="EntityType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Attribute" type="AttributeType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" />
    </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Looking for that issue since hours, and I still don't find an error. Can you spot me the right direction? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XML Representation of Element Declaration Schema Components](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-element):

> **{target namespace}**
>
> If `form` is present and its *actual value* is `qualified`, or if `form` is absent and the *actual value* of `elementFormDefault` on the `<schema>` ancestor is `qualified`, then the *actual value* of the `targetNamespace` [attribute] of the parent `<schema>` element information item, or *absent* if there is none, otherwise *absent*.

Since the default value of `elemeFormDefault` is `unqualified`, unless otherwise specified the local elements must be unqualified.

Since you set the `xmlns="http://schemas.testxyzxyz.de/xyz/BusinessModel"`, the `Entities` became qualified.
The fix is to set `elementFormDefault="qualified"` as @polishchuk wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.testxyzxyz.de/xyz/BusinessModel" xmlns:b="http://schemas.testxyzxyz.de/xyz/BusinessModel">
  <xsd:element name="BusinessModel" type="b:BusinessModelType" />
  <xsd:complexType name="BusinessModelType">
    <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xsd:element name="Entities" type="b:EntitiesType" />
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="EntitiesType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Entity" type="b:EntityType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="AttributeType">
    <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
    <xsd:attribute name="Type" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="EntityType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Attribute" type="b:AttributeType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1" />
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```