# XML schema and instance wrong

Tags: xml

I try the following xml schema

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="http://your_namespace"
        xmlns="http://your_namespace">
    <xsd:element name="person">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="firstname" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="lastname" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

and I assign it to this document

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<person xmlns="http://your_namespace"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://your_namespace
                C:\Program%20Files%20(x86)\Wattle%20Software\XMLwriter%202\Projects\ex.xsd">
    <firstname>aaa</firstname>
    <lastname>bbb</lastname>
</person>
```

but I always get an error for unexpected element firstname

Comment: You need to include elementFormDefault="qualified" in your XSD. See the following:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485955/error-while-validating-xml-against-xsd

Comment: could you write the full code please

Comment: Sure, added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485955/error-while-validating-xml-against-xsd) duplicate question. You need to add elementFormDefault="qualified" :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
        targetNamespace="http://your_namespace"
        xmlns="http://your_namespace">
    <xsd:element name="person">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="firstname" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="lastname" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```